# Assign the first non-zero value

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have the following variables defined:

```
a = 6
b = 4
c = 0
```

I want to assign the first non-zero value to another variable, but in reverse order (c -> b -> a). I originally tried `d = c || b || a`, but that still resulted in 0. Is there a one-liner way of doing this?

Comment: Another way is to not let the variables be 0 but let it be `nil` in such case. Often, it is better to avoid the trouble in the upstream rather than letting it happen and solve it later.

Comment: The numbers represent sizes of DataMapper collections, so they will only be numeric values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [detect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001485)

```
[c,b,a].detect { |i| i > 0 }
```

Comment: Or save two characters with `find`!

Comment: Thanks, this was really easy to implement!

Answer (score 0):

```
[c,b,a].select { |i| i > 0 }.first => 4
```